# Сортировка многомерного массива по ключу

Tags: массивы, php

Здраствуйте.
Есть

```
$torrents=array(
    array('text'=>'str1', 'seed'=>'2010'),
    array('text'=>'str1', 'seed'=>'210'),
    array('text'=>'str1', 'seed'=>'20109')
);
```

Как можно отсортировать по seed по убыванию?
Пробовал:
(foreach может лишний?)

```
$torrents=array();
    foreach(torrents as $key=>$arr){
        $seed[$key]=$arr['seed'];
    }
    array_multisort($seed, SORT_NUMERIC, $torrents);

    for($i=0; $i<count($torrents); $i++){
    // тут вывод инфы
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [uasort](https://www.php.net/uasort), предварительно описав свою функцию сравнения элементов массива по нужному полю.